# Ruby on Rails Add Text to QR Code Image Generated by RQRCODE_PNG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vue.js, qr-code

I am developing a Ruby on Rails website where I need to generate a QR code. I am using [rqrcode_png](https://github.com/DCarper/rqrcode_png) gem and it works well. But now I need to add a store ID below the image (the image that generated by the gem). Is this possible to do? Since I checked on the documentation, I can't find any clues about this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement for my app. I ended up making a view for the combined QR code + text. If you need to display it within another page, you can render it as a partial.

For example, I wanted a QR code that loads a reply form to a survey:

#### SurveysController

```
def qr
  @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
end

def qr_image
  qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new new_reply_url(slug: params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.png { send_data qr.as_png(size: 640), type: 'image/png', disposition: 'inline' }
    format.html { render html: qr.as_html.html_safe }
  end
end
```

#### surveys/qr.html.erb

In my case I wanted to display the name of a survey above the QR code.

```
<div class="row text-center">
  <h3 class="col-sm-12 "><%= @survey.name %></h3>

  <div class="col-sm-12 ">
    <%= image_tag qr_image_path(@survey) + ".png" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. But I want the text is combined with the image, since later the QR image will be downloaded.

Comment: I think for that, you would have to use something like image magic to post-process the png you get from RQRCode. rmagic https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick works well.